# No match for call to '...', when accessing to a declared variable in .h

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error from the line commented in the cpp code provided below.

error: no match for call to ‘(Camera_t {aka Pylon::CBaslerGigEInstantCamera}) (Pylon::IPylonDevice*)’
         camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice(infoCamera));

.h file:

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/gige/BaslerGigEInstantCamera.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace Pylon;

typedef Pylon::CBaslerGigEInstantCamera Camera_t;

    class BasCam : public eCamera {

    public:
        BasCam();
        void setCameraSettings();
        void startGrab();
        void ReleaseCamera();
    private:
        Camera_t camera;
        CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;
    };
```

.cpp file

```
#include "CamBas.h"
#include <string.h>

#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#include <pylon/gige/BaslerGigEInstantCamera.h>

using namespace Pylon;
using namespace std;

typedef Pylon::CBaslerGigEInstantCamera Camera_t;
using namespace Basler_GigECameraParams;

BasCam::BasCam() {

   CDeviceInfo infoCamera;
   infoCamera.SetDeviceClass(Camera_t::DeviceClass());

   //HERE IS THE ERROR:   
   camera(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice(infoCamera));    
   //        

   camera.Open();

   return;

}
```

If I set a new object as,

```
Camera_t cameraNew(CTlFactory::GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice(infoCamera));
```

it's working! However, when I am trying to use the declared 'camera' variable of same type in .h, it throws this error. What is wrong? How to access to it?

Comment: _Calling_ a class and creating a instance of a class are two different things.

Comment: Which will be the proper way to do it then?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.